# DropCap text in flutter

Tags: flutter

How can I achieve a drop cap text in flutter, I tried using drop_cap_text plugin on pub.dev, I achieved the drop cap text but when I change the app theme to dark mode all the text in the drop cap text widget does not change. Could others suggest any solutions for this, thanks.

Comment: It's impossible to tell you what to improve, if you don't show what you did. I suspect you did not pass the style to the widget. But that is wild guessing. Please provide a [mcve] of your dark mode problems with a description of what you expected and what happened instead.